# Как сделать бота на Roblox для афк?

Tags: roblox

Пытаюсь сделать бота для стойки на месте для roblox(не так что запуск клиента в фоновом режиме, нет. Нужно именно код, с использованием официального или сторонних api.) Кто примерно понимает как сделать. Язык - не важен.